# Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds - Section 26.2 Cohomology of a circle, tabular form.

Tags: manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I'm trying to understand how to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to compute Cohomologies. There's a small chapter in [Tu's Introduction to Manifolds](http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf) explaining the basics, with some basic theory.

More specifically section 26.2 has an example about the circle, later on there're other examples.
There's the following table which I don't quite understand how to read it, I also don't understand how it's filled:

[image]

The questions are:

1. How am I supposed to read the table?
2. How is it filled exactly? (I do understand the author covers $S^1$ with two overlapping circle arcs, which allows him to build a short exact sequence (I think this should correspond to a row of the table?) I think he's also using the zig-zag lemma, but not sure how. The exact entries are a bit of a mistery to me, especially all those zeros.
3. Is the Mayer-Vietoris sequence supposed to simplify the computation of cohomologies? With reference to this specific example to me what appears to happen in a sense is that the author still uses some of the previous results to fill some of the entries. However by the use of problem 26.2 he's able to compute the dimension of H^1(S^1) right away, without passing through the calculations done in the example 24.4. But it doesn't seem to me it simplified that much.

Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assuming you're familiar with the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, you know it goes $0 \to 1 \to 2$ in grading, so you read each row left to right, and you start from the bottom and go to the top.
2. Each point in the table is filled with the homology group of the degree from the row, and the space from the column. The whole point of MV is to use simpler spaces for which you know the cohomology. In this case, these are two arcs that intersect in two points. Since arcs are contractible, their cohomologies are $\mathbb{R}$ in degree $0$ and $0$ otherwise. Usually you use a short exact sequence of (co)chain complexes, specifically $$0 \to C^n (X \cup Y) \xrightarrow{i} C^n(X \coprod Y) \xrightarrow{j} C^n (X\cap Y) \to 0$$ and apply the zig-zag lemma to get Mayer-Vietoris in the first place, so you don't actually have to go through this. The actual Mayer-Vietoris sequence has all the terms in cohomology already written out, so all you have to do is plug and play.
3. Usually it's a pretty useful tool. Here the space is $S^1$ so it's already pretty simple. But suppose I asked you to calculate the de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{p,q\}$ i.e. a plane punctured twice? MV could help you (though there are other ways for sure). Just checked the book and on page $302$ he calculates the cohomology groups of a torus using MV, that could be illuminating. After further skimming, a lot of chapter $28$ can help illustrate the power of MV.

Comment: For 1. Why does the third row (bottom one) have four terms and the two topmost only three? Also the MV sequence is constructued using short exact sequences (which are $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$. For 2. you mention homologies, I don't think the author even defines homologies. For 3. I guess I need to go a bit further then

Comment: 1. The sequence extends by $0$ in both directions and usually it gives good information to have that $0$, so you have that extra $0$ in the botttom row. I know it's constructed using short exact sequences of cochain complexes, but you don't have to write this down each time, or run through it, or use the zig-zag lemma each time. The sequence is a theorem in its own right, so you can always just construct the table and write out the sequence without worrying about the "underlying" S.E.S and the zig-zag lemma. 2. Oops, I meant cohomology. Force of habit...

Comment: ...but regardless each entry is just the corresponding cohomology group.

Comment: Still for 1. How are all the entries computed? I'm still missing that bit. To me what's happening is that table has been filled with results previously derived, am I wrong?

Comment: No you're not wrong! Each entry is from a previous result. For Mayer-Vietoris you use spaces $U$ and $V$ such that you already know their cohomologies beforehand. You can see he says that $U$ and $V$ are both diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ so he uses the cohomology groups for $\mathbb{R}$ to fill it in.

Comment: Ok, but if this is the case how does the MV sequence simplify the computation then? Since we need to prove further results this is probably what's confusing me.

Comment: Again, you choose $U$ and $V$ such that you know results beforehand. As you deal with more complex spaces, you usually build up a repertoire of spaces whose cohomology you already know. Currently for example, you have the cohomology of $\mathbb{R}$ and were able to use it for $S^1$. Now that you know for $S^1$, you can calculate the cohomology of something like a figure $8$. The simplification comes from choosing a good $U$ and $V$ beforehand.

Comment: I would suggest reading through this example, and then finishing the homotopy invariance chapter and moving onto the computations chapter, which probably has more examples of place you can use MV.

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old post, but in this table why are all entries beyond $H^1(S^1)$ zero? Since $S^1$ is one dimensional it is obvious why $H^k$ is zero for all subsets $k \geq 2$, but what about $H^1$ of the disjoint union or $H^1(U \cap V)$? I read in a few other places that it is due to homotopy, but this section of the book comes before Tu introduces homotopy methods for cohomology. Is there a way to see that without it?

Comment: @CBBAM the answer is in the book, right at the start of chapter 26.2 - "Since an open arc is diffeomorphic to an open interval and hence to the real line $\mathbb{R}^1$, the cohomology rings of $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic to that of $\mathbb{R}^1$..." so the author is assuming you know the cohomology of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @OsamaGhani Why does that imply $H^1$ is zero? Is it because $H^0$ consists of constant functions, so their (exterior) derivative is zero?

Comment: @CBBAM See the start of 24.2 i.e. Example 24.3 . Essentially there are three steps: $\mathbb{R}$ is connected so $H^0(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$. Then, the author shows that all $1$-forms on $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and also exact, so $H^1(\mathbb{R}) = 0$ and then lastly they use dimension to reason about any higher cohomologies

Comment: @OsamaGhani Thank you, now I understand.